# UTF8 Hex Codepoint to Decimal Mismatch

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, hex

I'm working on a program that takes the hex value of a unicode character and converts it to an integer, then to a byte array, then to a UTF-8 string. All is fine other than the fact that, for example, the hex value E2 82 AC (€ symbol) is 14 844 588 in decimal, but, if you look at the code point value of it on the web page provided below, it's 226 130 172, which is a big difference.

http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8320&number=128&names=-

If you sort the values their by decimal, they're not just converting the hex to decimal. Obviously I don't understand encodings as well as I thought I did.

E2 82 AC maps to 226 130 172 instead of 14 844 588.

Why is this discrepancy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot interpret a variable-length byte sequence as a number directly.  0x00E282AC is indeed 14844588 but this is just coincidental.

Comment: The byte sequence `0xE2` `0x82` `0xAC` in hex are individually `226` `130` `172` in decimal.  The single number `14,844,588` (notice the commas, which are just spaces in your question) is `0xE282AC` in hex.  The decimal numbers are `226` `130` `172`, not `226,130,172`. You are comparing two different things. You are letting the spaces confuse you.

Answer (score 2):

I think your statement, "the hex value E2 82 AC (€ symbol) is 14 844 588 in decimal", is incorrect.

How did you interpret the hex values `E2`, `82`, and `AC`?

hex `E2` = hex `E` * 16 + hex `2` = 14 * 16 +  2 = 226.

hex `82` = hex `8` * 16 + hex `2` =  8 * 16 +  2 = 130.

hex `AC` = hex `A` * 16 + hex `C` = 10 * 16 + 12 = 172.

So, the hex value E2 82 AC (€ symbol) is in fact 226 130 172 in decimal.